# Golang is timing out on my stream

Tags: go, streaming, httpresponse

I am trying to write a go server that receives a stream of data from an http request. The problem is that it times out once it receives `{status: connected}` How do I keep the connection alive?

```
func stream() {
    t := time.Now()
    a := t.Format("15:03")
    if a > string("08:30") && a < string("15:00") {
        color.Red("Streaming. . .")
        config := oauth1.NewConfig("HIDDEN", "HIDDEN")
        token := oauth1.NewToken("HIDDEN", "HIDDEN")
        httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)
        path := "https://stream.tradeking.com/v1/market/quotes.json?symbols=aapl"
        resp, _ := httpClient.Get(path)
        fmt.Println(resp)
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        fmt.Printf("Raw Response Body:\n%v\n", string(body))
        defer resp.Body.Close()
    } else {
        color.Red("%s \nMarkets are closed! Please, come back later.", t)
    }
}
```

I call this function in main. I also receive what looks like the header:
`&{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Date:[Mon, 16 Jan 2017 17:45:36 GMT] X-Powered-By:[Express] Server:[cloudflare-ngi
nx] Content-Type:[application/json] Connection:[keep-alive] Set-Cookie:[__cfduid=dcfcf86c79c56e659ce2b1bade3643c
981484588736; expires=Tue, 16-Jan-18 17:45:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.tradeking.com; HttpOnly] Vary:[Accept-Encodin
g] Cf-Ray:[322361d0efd40938-DFW]] 0xc42032e0c0 -1 [chunked] false true map[] 0xc4200d21e0 0xc42040cbb0}`

Comment: What is timing out? Are you setting a timeout yourself, or is the remote server timing out? And please, always check your errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out that the the market was closed for MLK Day and hence there was no response from the sever.

After a certain timeout, the remote server times out.